# Kubernetes cluster role admin not able to get deployment status

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have the following role:

`roleRef:
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    kind: ClusterRole
    name: admin`

When I do a `kubectl proxy --port 8080` and then try doing

`http://127.0.0.1:8080/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/cdp/deployments/{deploymentname}`

I get a `200` and everything works fine. However when I do:

`http://127.0.0.1:8080/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/cdp/deployments/{deploymentname}/status`

I get forbidden and a `403` status back .

I also am able to do `get`, `create`, `list`,`watch` on deployments with my `admin` role .

Any idea as to why `/status` would give forbidden when I clearly have all the necessary permission as admin for my namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the status subresource doesn't give you any more information than simply fetching the deployment

The admin role permissions do not let you write deployment status. They let you create and delete the deployment objects, controlling the "spec" portion of the object. Status modification permissions are granted to the deployment controller.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned verbs of the role and you didn't mention resources and apiGroup. Make sure the following are set:

```
  - apiGroups:
    - apps
    - extensions
    resources:
    - deployments/status
```